# Can't convert timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have an external API, I'm using for user information, but I can't convert their birthday to human date. 
The api output for the birthday is

```
"Birthday":"\/Date(-2208967200000-0600)\/"
```

How can I convert that date. I can't find any solutions online. 
No matter what I use it's always showing 1st, January 1900.

Comment: What date is that supposed to represent?

Comment: [Epoch Convertor](https://www.epochconverter.com/) says that it's GMT: Monday, 1 January 1900 06:00:00

Comment: It's not the right date. It's a birthday

Comment: @WilliamJames, What are the chances that the API provided bad data? That date is _definitely_ January 1st 1900.